# Finding count of a word in string using javascript in Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

This is the string from where I want to find a count of word

```
<table class="Label" rules="all" id="RegistrationGrid" style="width: 1020px; height: 355px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Mangal; color: Black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: buttonface; position: static; background-color: transparent; outline: 1px solid blue;" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4" border="3">   <tbody><tr style="color:White;background-color:SteelBlue;font-family:Verdana;font-size:X-Small;font-weight:normal;">    <th scope="col">DocNo</th><th scope="col">DName</th><th scope="col">RDate</th><th scope="col">SROName</th><th scope="col">Seller Name</th><th scope="col">Purchaser Name</th><th scope="col">Property Description</th><th scope="col">SROCode</th><th scope="col">Status</th><th scope="col" style="outline: 1px solid blue;">IndexII</th>   </tr><tr style="background-color:Transparent;">    <td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">9721</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">21/08/2017</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">राजकुमारी रमेशचंद्र तर्फे मुखत्यार धीरेन रमेशचंद्र</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">हरिहरन  मनी</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">सदनिका नं: ए-1905, माळा नं: 19, इमारतीचे नाव: ओबेरॉय एक्स्कविज़िट,ओबेरॉय गार्डन सिटीच्या जवळ, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगाव पूर्व मुंबई-400063, रोड : ऑफ वेस्टर्न एक्स्प्रेस हाईवे</td><td style="width: 1px; outline: 1px solid blue;">324</td><td style="width: 1px; outline: 1px solid blue;">4</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;"><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$0')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:AliceBlue;">    <td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">9719</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td>21/08/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>अनिल जयराम चौरसिया,सूरज जयराम चौरसिया</td><td>मेसर्स बियानी इंडस्ट्रिस चे प्रोपराईटर मुकेश बियानी तर्फे मुखत्यार संजय कुमार एम सिंह</td><td>सदनिका नं: टेनामेंट नं 19/150, माळा नं: तळ मजला, इमारतीचे नाव: मोतीलाल नगर नं 1, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगांव प मुंबई 104, रोड नं: गुलमोहर गल्ली, इतर  माहिती:  कालावधी 24 महिने मासिक भाडे रु. 20000/- अनामत रक्कम रु. 75000/-</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$1')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:Transparent;">    <td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">9583</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">लिव्ह अँणड लायसन्स </td><td>18/08/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>- - रिलायन्स इन्फ्रास्ट्रक्चर लिमिटेड चे सिनियर एक्जीक्यूटीव वाईस प्रेसिडेंट व कंपनी सेक्रेटरी श्री रमेश शेनॉय तर्फे मुखत्यार श्री सुनील सुरेश पाठक</td><td>- - नेस्को लिमिटेड चे चीफ फायनान्स ऑफिसर आणि हेड लीगल श्री दीपेश आर सिंघानिया</td><td>, इतर  माहिती: , इतर  माहिती: 223/अ/1अ,223/1,225,239/अ,240,241,241//2 ते 6,242ब,243/अ,248/अ मौजे गोरेगाव ता बोरिवली लिव्ह अँड लायसन्स कालावधी 30 वर्षे वार्षिक भाडे रु 1 मात्र क्षेत्रफळ 380 चौमी बांधीव एडिजे प्र क्र 1100902/327/2017 ता 06/07/2017</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$2')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:AliceBlue;">    <td>6169</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">03/06/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>सुवर्णा शरद रुपवते</td><td>रेश्मा राम सरूप शर्मा,राम सरूप एम शर्मा</td><td>सदनिका नं: टेनामेंट नं 28/224, माळा नं: अप्पर फ्लॉर, इमारतीचे नाव: एम एच बी कॉलनी, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगांव प मुंबई 104, रोड नं: मोतीलाल नगर नं 1 श्रावस्ती बुध्द विहार, इतर  माहिती:  कालावधी 11 महिने मासिक भाडे रु. 18500/- अनामत रक्कम रु. 50000/-</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$3')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:Transparent;">    <td>6118</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td>02/06/2017</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>प्रेम कुमार पानिकार</td><td>अजय तुकाराम ऐवळे</td><td>सदनिका नं: टेनामेंट नं 33/267, माळा नं: तळ व अप्पर फ्लॉर बेकसाईड, इमारतीचे नाव: संघमित्र को ऑप हौ सो लि, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगांव प मुंबई 104, रोड नं: मोतीलाल नगर नं 1, इतर  माहिती:  कालावधी 11 महिने मासिक भाडे रु. 10000/- अनामत रक्कम रु. 100000/-</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$4')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:AliceBlue;">    <td>6119</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td>02/06/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">पुष्पा वासुदेव पेवेकर</td><td>शिवराज  राठोड</td><td>सदनिका नं: 001, माळा नं: तळ मजला गुलमोहर बिल्डिंग, इमारतीचे नाव: अंकुर को ऑप हौ सो लि, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगांव प मुंबई 104, रोड नं: बेस्ट नगर मार्ग, इतर  माहिती:  कालावधी 11 महिने मासिक भाडे रु. 15000/- अनामत रक्कम रु. 60000/-</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$5')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:Transparent;">    <td>624</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">20/01/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>फारुख जे. मसानी</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">मेसर्स ग्रेटेक्स कॉर्पोरेट सर्वीसीज प्राईवेट लीमीटेड चे संचालक आलोक हरलालका</td><td>सदनिका नं: बी-702, माळा नं: 7, इमारतीचे नाव: इंपीरियल हाइट्स,गोरेगाव बस डेपोच्या मागे, ब्लॉक नं: बेस्ट कॉलनीच्या जवळ,ऑफ लिंक रोड, रोड नं: गोरेगाव पश्चिम मुंबई-400104</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$6')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:AliceBlue;">    <td>1586</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td>17/02/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>बद्रीलाल एन पटेल</td><td>कोतूल  पटेल,निनाद वी मनोहर</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">सदनिका नं: टेनामेंट नं बी-48/192, माळा नं: 1 ला मजला, इमारतीचे नाव: सिध्दा को ऑप हौ सो लि, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगांव प मुंबई 104, रोड नं: सिध्दार्थ नगर रोड नं 8, इतर  माहिती: कालावधी 12 महिने मासिक भाडे रु. 15000/- अनामत रक्कम रु. 100000/-</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$7')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:Transparent;">    <td>1021</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td>31/01/2017</td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>लीना राहुल नाईक</td><td>देबाशीष पी पाणिग्रहि</td><td>सदनिका नं: 903, इमारतीचे नाव: लव्हेंडर बिलडींग मंत्री पार्क सीएचएस लीमीटेड, ब्लॉक नं: न्यू दिंडोशी गोरेगाव पूर्व, रोड नं: फ़िल्म सिटी रोड,नियर एन. एन. पी. 1 अँड 2</td><td style="width: 1px; outline: 1px solid blue;">324</td><td style="width:1px;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$8')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="background-color:AliceBlue;">    <td>973</td><td>36-अ-लिव्ह अॅड लायसन्सेस</td><td>30/01/2017</td><td>सह दु.नि. बोरीवली 1 </td><td>अनिल सेहगल अँड गीता अनिल सेहगल तर्फे मुख त्यार राजेंद्र जैन</td><td>अभिषेक - मुखर्जी</td><td>सदनिका नं: 2704, माळा नं: 27, इमारतीचे नाव: वनेटसिआ(टावर ए),लोढा फियोरेन्जा, ब्लॉक नं: गोरेगाव पूर्व मुंबई-400063, रोड नं: ऑफ वेस्टर्न एक्स्प्रेस हाईवे</td><td style="width:1px;">324</td><td style="width: 1px; outline: 1px solid blue;">4</td><td><input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$9')" class="Button" type="button"></td>   </tr><tr style="color:Black;background-color:#CCCCCC;" align="left">    <td colspan="10"><table border="0">     <tbody><tr>      <td><span>1</span></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$2')" style="color:Black;">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$3')" style="color:Black;">3</a></td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$4')" style="color:Black;">4</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$5')" style="color:Black;">5</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$6')" style="color:Black;">6</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$7')" style="color:Black;">7</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$8')" style="color:Black;">8</a></td><td style="outline: 1px solid blue;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$9')" style="color:Black;">9</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$10')" style="color:Black;">10</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$11')" style="color:Black;">...</a></td>     </tr>    </tbody></table></td>   </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

This is the word which I want to count

```
<input value="IndexII" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$
```

This is what I have tried

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:RegistrationGrid&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET cnt EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var txt=s.split('<input value=\"IndexII\" onclick=\"javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','indexII$').length - 1);txt;")
PROMPT {{cnt}}
```

But it gives error `missing ) after argument list, line: 2 (Error code: -1001)`

Any suggestion changes should be made in my code to get the desired output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with the apostrophes: you are not escaping them.
See here:  `var txt=s.split('<input value=\"IndexII\" onclick=\"javascript:__doPostBack('` the last apostrophe terminates the split function's input

Comment: No Success ,Tried with "SET cnt EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var txt=s.split('<input value=\"IndexII\" onclick=\"javascript:__doPostBack(&quot;RegistrationGrid&quot;,&quot;indexII$&quot;)).length - 1;txt;")"

Comment: Try escaping with `\'` like this:
`SET cnt EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var txt=s.split('<input value=\"IndexII\" onclick=\"javascript:__doPostBack(\'RegistrationGrid\',\'indexII$\')).length - 1;txt;")`

Comment: Nope.. tried with your code , but it gave error "missing ) after argument list, line: 6 (Error code: -1001)"

Comment: Maybe you're missing an apostrophe then: 
`SET cnt EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var txt=s.split('<input value=\"IndexII\" onclick=\"javascript:__doPostBack(\'RegistrationGrid\',\'ind‌​exII$\')').length - 1;txt;")`

Answer (score 0):

```
SET cnt EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var txt=s.split('<input value=\"IndexII\" onclick=\"javascript:__doPostBack(\\\'RegistrationGrid\\\',\\\'indexII$').length - 1;txt;")
```

works for me.

You had a closing *)* too much in your code - this one is not needed `length - 1);txt`

Also, it seems the single *'* inside the param for the split need three \, so that after all nested escaping is done it reads as `'RegistrationGrid','indexII$` for the split function.

---

```
SET cnt EVAL("var s='\\\'RegistrationGrid\\\',\\\'indexII$';s;")
PROMPT {{cnt}}
```

Outputs `'RegistrationGrid','indexII$`, just what you want to search for in the split.